# Element or attribute do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName':')? NCName

Tags: xml, javabeans, configuration-files, dispatcher

I got this error with bean configuration, if some one is familiar with this error please help me out. The error is in the dispatcher-servlet.xml link below.

[dispatcher-servlet.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5P9X.png)

Comment: Post XML and source as text, never as an image.

Comment: And, the hover text error message *covers the XML* so we can't see the errant line.